# switching from https to ssh for bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have the ssh url of my repo

```
git@bitbucket.org:accountUser/repo.git
```

and my remote url for fetch and push:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org:accountUser/repo.git
```

I've generated a new private and publich ssh key, the private has been added to the  ssh agent and the public has been added to ssh keys in bitbucket.

If I use git-bash on the local server and put

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

it prints the accountUser matching the remote URL

However, git pull and git fetch return in powershell:

```
permission denied (publickey_ could not read from remote repository
```

and in gitbash it returns

```
invalid repository syntax, could not read from remote repository
```

after prompting for teh passphrase on the key.

What have I done wrong here? I'm just trying to fix the issues from bitbuckets disabling of TLS v1.1

Comment: See: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remote url

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org:accountUser/repo.git
```

has wrong syntax. Fix it:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountUser/repo.git
```

Comment: Confusion is likely because it can be git@bitbucket.org:<workspace_ID>/<repo_name>.git

 or 

ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<workspace_ID>/<repo_name>.git

Comment: @BeninCA This is [thoroughly documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls).